# What is the red joystick icon that is on some of the screenshot of Android phones?

Tags: applications

In some Android screenshots, I see this red joystick icon imposed on other app's screen:

[image]

What is this joystick app?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's [Game Genie](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.asus.gamewidget) included in [ZenUI](http://www.zenui.com) for the Asus ZenFone.

[image: screen shot from Play Store]